# Why does mount have the SUID bit set?

Tags: mount

I'm not sure why `mount` is installed with SUID bit on many distributions.

In graphical environment, it doesn't require user to type the `mount` command to mount a partition. Normally udisks will communicate with another daemon to mount the drive.

And on a server, I don't see the necessity as well.

So, is there any reason to have SUID bit set?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`mount()` requires root (or `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` on Linux), but it is possible to specify a mountpoint in `/etc/fstab` that is allowed to be mounted by a user by using the `users` option. To facilitate this, they need to elevate to the superuser account to be able to execute `mount()` successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the options used when the drives are `mount`ed.

Have a look at `/etc/fstab`, if the entry for the partitions in question has `defaults` set as an option then this implies that `suid` is set, from `man mount`[1]...

```
defaults
              Use default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async.
```

You can over-ride this by specifying alternative options in `/etc/fstab`, for example you can specify `users` as an option (although I was caught out by the fact that this implies `noexec` so I couldn't run any scripts and had to over-ride this), so have this in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
LABEL=home      /home       ext4    noatime,users,exec  0 4
```

[1] I was reading `man mount` and `man fstab` yesterday after having a problem with default options myself.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the question is about the mount binary having the setuid bit set, not about allowing suid files on the mounted filesystem, which is what the suid option does.

Comment: I agree, and your post (which was made whilst I was typing out mine) answers this directly (and is a depth of knowledge I don't have).  I thought that what I wrote would be useful to leave up as it provides some sort of practical work around (including the same solution of adding `users` in `/etc/fstab` but also highlights something which bit me yesterday which was the default options that `users` implies prevent execution and can over-ridden with `exec`).  Happy for it to be deleted though.