# mount and fstab: why can they be configured to allow users to mount but not umount?

Tags: mount, fstab, non-root-user

I noticed recently that is possible to allow normal user/s to mount a device through fstab, but apparently in any case umount can only be done by root.

Even the man page of mount only talks about mounting:

[image: mount man page]

Even more than having an actual solution to this, I'm wondering what's the reason behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind this, as with many Unix/Linux peculiarities, is of course historical. Unix, which itself evolved out of Unics ([a pun on its predecessor Multics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix#cite_ref-DMR_10-2)) was designed as a true *multi user* system. Users can log in either locally or remotely through `getty` and `login`, get a shell and and run their programs.

These days, the TTYs are virtual and `login` has been replaced by GDM/KDM, but utilities such as `mount`, `df`, `ls`, `ps` (which belong to [the oldest Unix commands](https://torgo-x.livejournal.com/1126334.html)) still remain largely unchanged in purpose, although they have acquired many additional features over the year.

The commands `mount` and `umount` were originally only meant to be run by the system administrator, or `root`. As Unix evolved and spread to personal computers both `mount` and `umount` [became SUID programs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107500/why-does-mount-have-the-suid-bit-set) to enable regular users to mount and unmount filesystems, but only under strict conditions. From `man mount`:

> Normally, only the superuser can mount filesystems. [...]
> Note  that mount is very strict about non-root users and all paths specified on command line are verified before fstab is parsed or a helper program is executed. [...]
> It  drops  suid permissions and continue as regular non-root user. [...]
> Only the user that mounted a filesystem can unmount it again.  If  any  user should  be able to unmount it, then use users instead of user in the fstab line.

Hence, both `mount` and `umount` are SUID programs that look for the `user` option or `users` option in `/etc/fstab`, then drop their root privileges and finally make the `mount()`/`umount()` system call.

Answer (score 2):

The man page also talks about unmounting, it is on your screenshot -- if you want to allow unmounting by any user, you need to use the `users` option.

> If any user should be  able to unmount it, then use users instead of user in the fstab line.

The reason for "promoting" the `user` option more is probably to prevent situations where one user mounts the device and second user unmounts it behind their back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll do further investigations because seems like in my system, with the fstab entry (I tried both user and users), only mount works without root, hence why I created this question